# How to draw a simple line in an SVG image using Batik?

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have an SVG image and I want to draw a simple line based on some coordinates on this image. I want to use Batik in Java to do this but don't know how and can't find enough documenations. Can someone help me?

Also if you are aware of any other Java libraries with which I can achieve this, please let me know!

Comment: I even cannot find any specific examples of how to open the svg file actually, if that gives you a starting point ;)